# Adding legend for color to ggplot with specific colors and linetype

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, visualization

I'd like to add a legend for the colors of the lines in a simple line plot and it isn't automatically being added. I need the colors and linetype to stay the same to match other figures in the paper. Here's a subset of the dataset, my code, and the current figure without the legend. I need a legend that says what color represents BP0, BP30 and BP60.

```
k   g   t   BP0 BP30    BP60
1   1   0   1   1   1
1   1   1   0.675595379 0.779756439 0.785879021
1   1   2   0.675595379 0.779756439 0.785879021
1   1   3   0.795819272 0.800062985 0.858646215
1   1   4   0.795819272 0.800062985 0.858646215
1   1   5   0.858646215 0.858646215 1
1   1   6   0.858646215 0.858646215 1
1   1   7   1   1   1
1   1   8   1   1   1
1   1   9   1   1   1
1   1   10  1   1   1
1   2   0   1   1   1
1   2   1   0.232239338 0.486624051 0.817310413
1   2   2   0.232239338 0.486624051 0.817310413
1   2   3   0.529274323 0.817310413 0.907445423
```

Code:

```
 RecoveryCombined <- as.data.frame(RecoveryCombined)
    plotcombined <- ggplot(data = RecoveryCombined, aes(x = t)) + 
      geom_line(aes(y= BP0), color = "cornflowerblue", lwd = 0.9) + 
      geom_line(aes(y= BP30), color = "chocolate1", linetype = "twodash", lwd = 0.9) +
      geom_line(aes(y= BP60), color = "darkslategrey", linetype = "longdash", lwd = 0.9) +
      facet_wrap(~k + g) +  
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 10, by = 1)) +
      labs(title = "Recovery Trajectory for BI = 200", x = "Time Period", y = "Relative Performance", color = "Legend")  + 
    print(plotcombined)
```

[image]

Comment: The ggplot-way is to reshape from wide to long and use the `colour` aesthetic to map the BP columns to colours. This will automatically create a legend.

Comment: Please take a look at the linked dupe post. The first (and highest rated) answer explains the approach.